# Set loader height and width in Adobe Flash and ActionScript

Tags: cs6, adobe-flash, actionscript

I have this source in Adobe Flash CS6 (AS3).

```
var loader:Loader =new Loader();
imageViewer_mc.addChild(loader);     
loader.x=65;
loader.y=50;
loader.load(new URLRequest("image.jpg"));
```

`image.jpg` size is `200px X 400px` and viewing nice in pages. But when I replace it with `600px X 1200px` Image, It doesn't have previous size. I know that something is wrong with my code; But I don't know where is it.

My clear question: ***How can I load different images in a loader with same size?***

( Can I fit images to their container, `imageViewer_mc`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, even though you are adding the loader to the parent `imageViewer_mc` movieclip, the loader will not have the same size as its parent.

You can set the width and height of the loaded image as follows:

```
var loader:Loader =new Loader();
imageViewer_mc.addChild(loader);     
loader.load(new URLRequest("image2.jpg"));

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(){
    loader.content.width = 200;
    loader.content.height = 400;
});
```

A graphic-based solution, to a different effect, would be to simply crop the image with a layer mask. (New Layer, Right-Click Mask, Unlock, Draw shape to crop within it).

Answer (score 0):

In ActionScript 3 (Flash CS4 OR higher), its better to use `UILoader` component instead of `MovieClip`.

For loading images you we use:

```
imageViewer_mc.source="image.jpg";
```

We can set objects properties visual. This way fits image to loader and resizes file with proportions.